# How to vectorize a for loop with nested if from RL code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, reinforcement-learning

I have this loop that I would like ideally to vectorize:

```
for state, action, reward, next_state, done in batch:
      reward = reward
      if not done:
        reward = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]) 
      target = self.model.predict(state)[0]
      target[action] = reward
```

If you are familiar with RL, this is a batch from the memory.

In this case, state is an array with 10 elements, same as next_state (input to DQN). `Action` is an integer (index of the output vector), `reward` is a float and `done` is boolean.

I tried to convert batch into a dataframe. What is difficult for me is to vectorize the following line:
`target[action] = reward`

The element of target with index `action` should get the reward value from the bellman's equation (`reward = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])`) if `done == False`. The remaining get the `self.model.predict(state)[0]`

Any ideas?

Comment: To "vectorize" a loop like this you have to re-write functions like the `model.predict` to work with all batches at once.  The "vectorization" that offers big speed gains uses compiled `numpy` methods that operate on whole array.  It replaces slow python-level iteration with fast 'c' level iterations.

Comment: Yes, try to pass the inputs to the network as a batch itself instead of single states.

Comment: I actually have managed that. My problem is to change specific elements of all the rows in the 2d numpy array